# Numbered paragraphs in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, styles, numbering, outline

I have the following styles defined in Word 2007. They all have outline levels 1-6. They also correctly show up in the Table of Contents (not all, I only set the TOC up to Level 3).

> **1 Heading 1
>
>   1.1 Heading 2
>
>   1.1.1 Heading 3
>
>   1.1.1.1 Heading 4
>
>   1.1.1.1.1 Heading 5
>
>   1.1.1.1.1.1 Heading 6**

This is what I want

> **1 Heading 1**
>   1.1 Body text under Heading Level 1
>   1.2 Body text under Heading Level 1
>
> **2 Heading 1**
>   **2.1 Heading 2**
>   2.1.1 Body text under Heading Level 2
>   2.1.2 Body text under Heading Level 2
>   2.1.3 Body text under Heading Level 2
>
> **2.2 Heading 2**
>   2.2.1 Body text under Heading Level 2
>   2.2.2 Body text under Heading Level 2

How do I make two list sequences link to each other? Here's a **{fill in the blanks}** illustration:

> **{section number} Heading 1**
>   {section number}.{clause number} Body text under Heading Level 1
>   {section number}.{clause number} Body text under Heading Level 1

The example above should expand to:

> **1 Heading 1**
>   1.1 Body text under Heading Level 1
>   1.2 Body text under Heading Level 1

Another example:

> **{section number} Heading 1
>
>   {section number}.{subsection number} Heading 2**
>   {section number}.{subsection number}.{clause number} Body text under Heading Level 2
>   {section number}.{subsection number}.{clause number} Body text under Heading Level 2

should expand to:

> **2 Heading 1**
>   **2.1 Heading 2**
>   2.1.1 Body text under Heading Level 2
>   2.1.2 Body text under Heading Level 2
>   2.1.3 Body text under Heading Level 2

The numbered body text paragraphs shouldn't show up the Table of Contents. I couldn't find the right way to do that, whether in multilevel lists, fields, styles, etc. How do I do it right?

If at all possible, I would like to define just one **Body Text** style linked to a numbered multi-level list. The numbers in the multi-level list should adjust according to the section (or subsection, or subsubsection number) to which it belongs.

Here's a screenshot of my problem. See the body text numbering that won't adjust accordingly:
[image]

**In response to DMA57361:**
Unfortunately, the problem persists:
[image]

I think it's in the way that Word 2007 organizes outline lists (now called Multilevel Lists). I have the following Multilevel Lists defined and linked to the respective Styles:

> **Headings Multilevel List:**
>   Level 1 -> Heading 1
>   Level 2 -> Heading 2
>   Level 3 -> Heading 3
>   and so on...
>
> **Clauses Multilevel List:**
>   Level 1 -> (none)
>   Level 2 -> Clause 1
>   Level 3 -> Clause 2
>   and so on...

I wonder if it is possible for a Style in one Multilevel List to **"get"** the outline number it belongs to? For example, Clause 1 style should detect that it belongs to section 1, or section 2, then adjust its numbering accordingly. Clause 2 style should detect that it belongs under subsection 3.2, or even subsection 4.5, then adjust its numbering accordingly.

How unfortunate this is for Word 2007. Anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it worked for me. I included the numbered body text paragraphs in the multilevel list system. The downside is that I can only use up to 4 outline levels.

"Restart list after" must be set in the following manner:

```
Level          Restart after
1 (Heading 1)        
2 (Clause 1)   1
3 (Heading 2)  1
4 (Clause 2)   3    
5 (Heading 3)  3
6 (Clause 3)   5
7 (Heading 4)  5
8 (Clause 4)   7
```

I customized the font properties (Bold) for the numbering of the Clauses.

"Include level number from" must be set accordingly. For example, for Level 5 (Heading 3), only level numbers from 1 and 3 must be included. Similarly, for Level 6 (Clause 3), only level numbers from 1, 3 and 5 must be included.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

***Almost***, the following will do what you want *except* that you'll also need one body style per level (the same as you need one heading style per level), instead of one style overall. And please note that I'm doing these in Word 2003 so they actual motions may be slightly different.

## Build Styles

Get up the styles pane, IIRC in Word 2007 you hit the small down arrow on the bottom-right of the styles selector on the ribbon. Click on the **New Style** button, on Word 2007 I think this is a pictoral button of a letter `A` with a gleam/star on it.

Each new style should be **Based On** a corresponding `Heading` entry, this ensures they will stay within the correct numbering pattern, *because they're using exactly the same pattern*. Obviously, you'll need to remove bold, adjust the font size, adjust the paragraph spacing, and whatever else you need to ensure the body text appears how you want it to.

You probably will want to create `BodyText1` based on `Heading2`, `BodyText2` based on `Heading3`, and so on for however many levels you will need.

Instead, you *might* be able to base `BodyText2` (etc) on `BodyText1`, and just adjust the numbering level, but for some reason this caused me a problem. Not sure why, but you may wish to try so you don't have to redefine the font size/etc for each `BodyText` style.

## Adjust Table of Contents

Because the new styles are based on the `Heading` ones they will appear in the table of contents. Obviously, this is not desirable.

*This is where my memory of Word 2007 memory becomes hazy, the following is purely Word 2003 - if it doesn't match, let me know and I'll update for Word 2007 once I'm home and can check directly.*

Right click on your current Table of Contents and select **Edit field...**, then click the **Table of Contents** button to get to the TOC window. (You can probably get here when creating a brand new TOC as well)

Click the **Options** button (bottom-right) and then find each `BodyText` style in the list; *clear* the **TOC Level** field from each of these. This ensures the `BodyText` items will not appear in the TOC at all. Close each window until you get back to your document, you might be asked if you want to replace the current table, if so click Yes.

## Use the styles

Now just ensure you set the relevant style on each paragraph as you write.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't gotten beyond __Build Styles__. See my edits to my question.

Comment: @Kit, Hmmm, OK - I'll have a review of this using Word 2007 directly once I'm home this evening and will update as appropriate. -- My first thought (without W2007 to hand) is to try basing Clause1 on Heading2 (both `x.x` format) and Clause2 on Heading3 (`x.x.x`), etc - not on the same numbered heading.

Comment: @Kit, I've just tried this at home on Word 2007 - and basing each `Clause` style on the next header (so `Clause1` is based on `Header2`) seems to be working for me. This was done *without* touching the numbering / list setup at all.

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer twice for the effort and insights (I placed it on the comment instead), but I added my own solution which worked perfectly for me.