# How do I number paragraphs in Word without affecting the headings?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am trying to make a template with numbered paragraphs, but I don't want the paragraph numbering to affect the heading numbering. 
It currently looks like this:

```
1    Heading 1

2    Heading 2

2.1  Subheading 2.1

3    Heading 3
     [1] Some paragraph text.
     [2] Another paragraph.

3.2  Subheading 3.1
     [1] Some more paragraph text.
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
1    Heading 1

2    Heading 2

2.1  Subheading 2.1

3    Heading 3
     [1] Some paragraph text.
     [2] Another paragraph.

3.1  Subheading 3.1
     [1] Some more paragraph text.
```

Note the difference in sub-heading 3.1.

What I've done is used numbering. I've associated Heading 1 with level 1 and so on down to Heading 4 and leevel 4. I've then associated paragraph text with level 5 and had it only display the last number. The problem is that this means that if I add paragraph text after a level 1 heading it will increment the level 2 counter as well.

I can artificially fix it in each case by manually selecting a heading and choosing "Restart Numbering", but this will be a common occurrence, and I'm making this a template for hundreds of people to use, so I'd like to avoid too much manual work if I can.

What I want is that the paragraphs operate on a different counter to the ehadings, but that this counter is reset each time there is a new heading - or something to that effect. I've looked at other questions, but none seem to capture what I need. [Numbered paragraphs in Word 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/229704/numbered-paragraphs-in-word-2007) seems the closest, but I couldn't really follow that, and I don't think it was close enough.

I am working with Microsoft Word 2003, but the version is likely to change soon, so any solution would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Word MVP article "[Methods for Restarting Numbering](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/numbering/ListRestartMethods.htm)" describes multiple methods, including a higher-level heading style, VBA code, or a LISTNUM field.

In your situation, the higher-level heading style sounds like what you already tried. It doesn't really work because you can't predict which heading level will show up before your list, and there doesn't appear to be a way to reset numbering after multiple different styles.

The best option might be using LISTNUM fields, as described [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/numbering/ListRestartByLISTNUM.htm). After each list, add the following field code: {LISTNUM \l 1 \s 0}. Note that this displays as zero, so it needs to be hidden.

I'd recommend creating a style for the field code to keep it hidden (for example, making the font white or setting it as hidden text).

Adding this field after every single list may not be a lot less effort than renumbering every new list, but you can make it a Quick Part to avoid having to retype it.